# SERVICE 'meminfo' DUMP TIMEOUT (10s) EXPIRED

Tags: android, dumpsys

when I execute command line: dumpsys meminfo 
in my android shell enviroment (Android 8.1)

I got the output: *** SERVICE 'meminfo' DUMP TIMEOUT (10s) EXPIRED ***

Does Anyone can tell me how to avoid the issue without rebooting the device?

Because I am developing a function that monitor the memories of all processes when the device is running

Comment: use argument -t <TIMEOUT> will solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Henry.Woo says is right.

use:
adb shell dumpsys -t 60 meminfo